# Complex Analysis vs. $\mathbb{R}^2$ Integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I'm wondering about the following I'm somewhat shocked about, since I wasn't too aware of it, so I'm asking here for clarification or if it is even true...

Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic. When calculating the closed loop integral over the contour $C$ and converting to real and imaginary parts, I get the following
$$0=\oint_C f(z) \, {\rm d}z = \oint_C (u+iv) \, {\rm d}(x+iy) \\
=\oint_C \left\{ u \, {\rm d}x - v \, {\rm d}y + i\left(u \, {\rm d}y + v \, {\rm d}x\right) \right\} \\
=\oint_C \begin{pmatrix}u \\ -v \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} {\rm d}x \\ {\rm d}y \\ {\rm d}z \end{pmatrix} + i \oint_C \begin{pmatrix}v \\ u \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} {\rm d}x \\ {\rm d}y \\ {\rm d}z \end{pmatrix} \, .
$$

In the last step I interpreted the planar curve $C$ as part of ${\mathbb{R}}^3$. Now because of the $i$ each term has to vanish separately.

Let's consider the first term first: Because $u$ and $v$ are harmonic functions, they are differentiable and thus Stokes theorem can be applied. The first term then becomes $$0=\int_A {\rm d}\vec{A} \cdot \nabla \times \begin{pmatrix}u \\ -v \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = -\int_A {\rm d}\vec{A} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \partial_x v + \partial_y u \end{pmatrix}$$
where $A$ is any oriented area bounded by the planar curve $C$. Therefore $\begin{pmatrix}u \\ -v \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ is integrable and can be expressed as a gradient i.e. $\begin{pmatrix}u \\ -v \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\nabla \phi(x,y)$.

Plugging this into the CR-equations, it all makes sense
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = - \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \Delta \phi = 0$$
i.e. $\phi$ is harmonic. The second equation reads $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y \partial x} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x \partial y}$$ which is true due to Schwarz.

I see that starting from the CR-equations and expressing $u$ and $v$ as a gradient, they are automatically fulfilled. But does this also mean that this is true in all generality? For every holomorphic function, the real and imaginary part is a gradient of some scalar potential $\phi$ that is harmonic i.e. every holomorphic function $f(z)$ can be decomposed as $$f(z) = \partial_x \phi - i\partial_y \phi = 2\,\partial_z \phi \, .$$

Since $\phi$ is harmonic, i.e. $4\partial_\bar{z}\partial_z \phi=0$, it can be written as
$$\phi(x,y) = \tilde{\phi}(z,\bar{z}) = \phi_1(z) + \phi_2(\bar{z}) \, ,$$
since mixed terms can not arise. But now $\phi$ is real $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, so $\phi_2=\bar{\phi}_1$. So essentially it boils down to the fact that the 2d-laplacian nicely factorizes upon the variable transformation $(x,y)\rightarrow (z,\bar{z})$.

Comment: your last equation asks if $f$ has a holomorphic primitive ($2\phi$) and that is true on simply connected domains so in particular on the contour and its interior - so you can take if you want any primitive and add a conjugate holomorphic function and get many such $\psi, 2\partial_{z} \psi = f$

Comment: There's not really a question here, but the real and imaginary parts are well known to be harmonic, and, as Conrad has said, given a harmonic function $\phi(x,y)$ in the plane we can often find a conjugate harmonic function $\psi(x,y)$ for which $\phi + i\psi$ is holomorphic when treated as a function of $z := x + iy $(this is always possible over a simply connected domain, and is an exercise in homology over multiply-connected domains)